# rpc failed, curl 56 GnuTLSrecv error (-54)

Tags: software-installation, opencv, git

Hi guys my goal is to create an opencv directory and clone opencv and opencv_contrib on a raspberry pi this is why I entered the following command:
pi@raspberrypi:~/opencv $ git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git

The output was the following:
Cloning into 'opencv'...

- remote: Enumerating objects: 308048, done.
- remote: Counting objects: 100% (66/66), done.
- remote: Compressing objects: 100% (51/51), done.
- **error**: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-54): Error in the pull function.
- **error**: 5637 bytes of body are still expected
- fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
- fatal: early EOF
- fatal: index-pack failed

I have no idea what that means and would be really thankful for some help :)